# Is there a function for generating settings.SECRET_KEY in django?

Tags: django, django-settings

I wrote an [ansible-role for openwisp2](https://github.com/nemesisdesign/ansible-openwisp2/) to ease its deployment, it's a series of django apps. To ease the deployment as much as possible, I wrote a simple (probably trivial) [SECRET_KEY generator script](https://github.com/nemesisdesign/ansible-openwisp2/blob/master/files/generate_django_secret_key.py):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Pseudo-random django secret key generator
"""
from __future__ import print_function
import random

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' \
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ' \
        '0123456789' \
        '#()^[]-_*%&=+/'

SECRET_KEY = ''.join([random.SystemRandom().choice(chars) for i in range(50)])

print(SECRET_KEY)
```

which is called by ansible to generate the secret key the first time the ansible playbook is run.

Now, that works fine BUT I think it defeats the built-in security measures Django has in generating a strong key which is also very hard to guess.

At the time I looked at other ways of doing it but didn't find much, now I wonder: **is there a function for generating settings.SECRET_KEY in django?**

That would avoid this kind of home baked solutions that even though they work they are not effective when it comes to security.

Comment: I found that it was easier to generate a key in [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Indeed, you can use the same function that generates a new key when you call `startproject`, which is [`django.core.management.utils.get_random_secret_key()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/core/management/utils.py#L82).

Note however it's not very different from your version.

Comment: I thought it had some more security built into it but I was wrong. Anyway, it's probably better to use that function since it may be improved in the future.

Comment: actually `get_random_string` is a quite bit better than my version:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py#L54-L77

Comment: Is is ok to write in settings.py? `SECRET_KEY=django.core.management.utils.get_random_secret_key()`

Comment: @Psddp You can do that, but it would mean that every time your app starts/restarts you are going to get a new secret key, meaning that all existing sessions, cookies, etc, will be invalidated. If that's not something you use or care about then that could work, but it still feels like it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 120):

Note that this may not be safe to use for production, as `S Ghosh` is pointing out in a post below. But copy and paste this after running `django-admin shell` for example to quickly get a key.

```
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key  
get_random_secret_key()
```

Comment: This solution is using python's secrets lib on the back, so, cool!

You can find it in Django's crypto.py file [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/bfe9665502c77baf14ce6cf52af974033bd43164/django/utils/crypto.py#L62):
`return ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length))`

Comment: "Note that this may not be safe to use for production, as S Ghosh is pointing out in a post below. " - Starting from tag version 3.1.3 `get_random_secret_key` is using secrets module

Answer (score 46):

Run this command below on the Terminal.

```
$ python -c 'from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key; print(get_random_secret_key())'
```

output:

```
2x$e%!k_u_0*gq0s4!_u(2(^lpy&gir0hg)q&5nurj0-sseuav
```

Answer (score 20):

I would like to add that as per the commit [Fixed #31757 -- Adjusted system check for SECRET_KEY to warn about autogenerated default keys](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b7f500396e05cd1f0bb8901fce16e2d8393d2779#diff-f9c36a153fc9f4620438a7d8a2f22b35ba7581c145853890b1f6e3f3fa6bf3b3), the method `get_random_secret_key()` is considred to be insecure.

If you are using python 3.6+ then you can use the `secrets.token_hex([nbytes=None])` function

```
python3 -c 'import secrets; print(secrets.token_hex(100))'
```

credit [TLDR: Generate Django Secret Key](https://humberto.io/blog/tldr-generate-django-secret-key/)

Comment: Is there a way to include upper and mixed case characters? thanks!

Comment: @xjlin0 Will you use the code in Django project? Then check the detailed answer given by hlongmore.

Comment: Was your conclusion that the `get_random_secret_key()` method is insecure because they added an "insecure" prefix to it? I think they added the prefix so it can be detected with some automatic checking tools (disclaimer: I haven't done read the discussion on [the ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31757) and [the mailing](https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/CIPgeTetYpk) list yet).

Comment: @hashlash yes you are correct, but I think that the latest version has this solved. See the detailed answer by hlongmore.
The only issue with `get_random_secret_key()` is that you cannot create a key of arbitrary length, say 60 chars, 50 is all you get.

Answer (score 11):

The post referenced by S Ghosh [TLDR: Generate Django Secret Key](https://humberto.io/blog/tldr-generate-django-secret-key/) indicates that as of version 3.1.3, Django is actually using the Python `secrets` module behind the scenes. Looking at [this blob](https://github.com/django/django/blob/840ad06300ac38e0e0e18ea36d6969cc03c875a9/django/core/management/utils.py#L77) for `get_random_secret_key` and [this other blob](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d10c7bfe56f025ccc690721c9f13e7029b777b9c/django/utils/crypto.py#L51) for `get_random_string`, I can see it is so:

```python
def get_random_secret_key():
    """
    Return a 50 character random string usable as a SECRET_KEY setting value.
    """
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
    return get_random_string(50, chars)
```

```python
def get_random_string(length, allowed_chars=RANDOM_STRING_CHARS):
    """
    Return a securely generated random string.
    The bit length of the returned value can be calculated with the formula:
        log_2(len(allowed_chars)^length)
    For example, with default `allowed_chars` (26+26+10), this gives:
      * length: 12, bit length =~ 71 bits
      * length: 22, bit length =~ 131 bits
    """
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length))
```

The only issue with the `get_random_secret_key` function as I see it in the code is that the allowed characters does not include capital letters, so the number of possible bits for the same size key is smaller than it would be if capitals were included, but not by much:

```python
from math import log2
lower_plus_numbers = (list(chr(o) for o in range(0x61, 0x7B))
                      + list(chr(o) for o in range(0x30, 0x3A)))
punctuation = list('!@#$%^&*(-_=+)')
upper_alpha = list(chr(o) for o in range(0x41, 0x5B))
shorter = log2((len(lower_plus_numbers) + len(punctuation)) ** 50)
longer = log2((len(lower_plus_numbers) + len(punctuation) + len(upper_alpha)) ** 50)
print(f'longer: {int(longer + 0.5)}; shorter: {int(shorter + 0.5)} '
      f'difference: {int(longer - shorter + 0.5)}; ratio: {longer/shorter}')
```

The output of the above code:

```plaintext
longer: 312; shorter: 282; difference: 30; ratio: 1.1070316647619918
```

So, if you have a recent enough Django and Python, the biggest question is whether you want to generate your `SECRET_KEY` with a dependency on Dango, or just Python. If you don't mind the Django dependency, but want to include upper case letters, or want to have a longer key, you can easily do something like:

```python
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
key_length = 60
get_random_string(
    key_length,
    allowed_chars=lower_plus_numbers + punctuation + upper_alpha,
)
```

Sample output:

```python
'gW(VDtylhoAuZNcLbIC=ai5=2*tPZ=Gmf4D1^4T!NxX3tB0%_w7pYY2+FgDx'
```

If you don't want the Django dependency, you could use S Ghosh's answer. Or if you want more than hex characters, you could do something like:

```python
allowed_chars = [chr(i) for i in range(0x21, 0x7F)]
key_length = 60
key = ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(key_length))
```

Value of `key` (as a python string):

```python
'DN7tbWid#q6R^=%i"[1AA>$@AZg=XD+p|[aB?:#V`:kKWL77P6dC,~(\\9O\'j'
```